# ASUS F402CA-WX102H random crashes after UEFI Secure Boot disabled

Tags: linux, boot, debian, uefi

I have a ASUS F402CA-WX102H notebook.

- I disabled UEFI Secure Boot, booted on USB and installed Debian Wheezy (double boot with Windows8 for now).
- The installation process worked fine, but the laptop random crashed both on Linux and Windows after a couple of minutes or less.
- So I reinitialized the BIOS (hence re-enabling the Secure Boot): I can start W8 and it works fine, but of course can't boot on Debian.
- If I disable again Secure boot, the problem is back.

Note:

- I wouldn't mind deleting all windows & partitions, if it could help...
- I could run all the Debian installation process well (something like an hour), so it seems, it's not merely a problem of running another OS in disabled mode that triggers the problem.
- I don't know if I have to or if it even makes sense to run to this complicated process described for Ubuntu like there:
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/91484/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-efi-uefi

Any help, any idea what could cause or what could disable these crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try upgrading your firmware. What you describe reeks of a firmware bug, so an update might fix it.

If that fails, you can try adding Secure Boot support for Debian. I haven't followed Debian's Secure Boot policies very closely, but it's certainly possible to add Secure Boot support for any Linux distribution. I've written two Web pages on the subject:

- My [generic Secure Boot page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) describes enabling Secure Boot in general terms. You probably want to follow the "Using a Signed Boot Loader" section. Unless Debian is now signing its GRUB binaries and kernels and you can find the Debian public key file, using PreLoader is likely to be a bit easier than using shim.
- My [rEFInd Secure Boot page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) describes using Secure Boot with rEFInd specifically. If you're not using rEFInd, this page is less likely to be useful than the first one, but you might still pick up a thing or two, so it might be worth skimming.

One more thought occurs to me: It could be that something about GRUB 2, and not Secure Boot, is causing the prooblems. When you enable Secure Boot, the firmware bypasses GRUB 2 and boots Windows via its own boot loader; but when you disable Secure Boot, the computer boots through GRUB 2. You could test this hypothesis by disabling Secure Boot and using the firmware's own boot manager or a USB flash drive or CD-R version of [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) to boot Windows *without* involving GRUB. If the problems go away, then that's strong evidence that GRUB is doing something weird. If that's the case, you should install another EFI boot manager. See [this set of pages](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) for a description of what's available. That said, I've never heard of this type of problem before, so it seems like a long-shot. Still, it's easy enough to test, and so is worth investigating -- maybe before trying to add Secure Boot support for booting Linux.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. (Un)fortunately the answer is much easier, it was just an hardware defect, triggered mostly by a key stroke which I didn't used under windows and hence not recognized...maybe your post will help once the hardware defect recovered :)